# How to handle Spinners when screen orientation changes?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-lifecycle

I have two Spinners. In `onCreate` i setup listeners for them. At some other places i populate them.

Now I am not sure what the best practice is for handling these spinners when screen orientation changes. Should i store all values and selected item in `sharedPreferences` somehow or in `savedInstanceState`?

If you can, please advise me in a prefered way and also include some sample code for handling spinners. The goal here is to keep the values and selected item thru the lifecycle.

I will include code at request or if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in your AndroidManifest file, it will keep spinner value selected on orientation change.

User Spinner Like this:

```
mSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        stringArrayList.add("List Item " + i);

    }

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringArrayList);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, `onSaveInstanceState` for Screen Orientation for saving your selected value of spinner,According to my choice `shared preference` is not good choice for saving selected values of spinner.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("mySpinner", mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
    // do this for each or your Spinner
 }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // initialize all your visual fields        
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mySpinner.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("mySpinner", 0));
        // do this for each of your text views
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the value/selection in onCreate. However the spinner value is still reverting to the default value. Perhpas it is an issue with the adapter?

Comment: i'm no getting you @singhnikhil

Comment: @thelastchief can you show what you tried? on screen rotation is data available to adapter before you set the selection?